# Como obter o diretório temporário padrão do sistema operacional em PHP?

Tags: php, diretório, sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos

No PHP, existe alguma maneira [ou alguma função que tenha a finalidade] de obter o diretório onde são salvos arquivos temporários em um determinado sistema operacional?

Eu sei que a função `tempnam` gera um nome temporário para um arquivo. Quando o diretório passado por primeiro parâmetro não existe, ele retorna um nome de arquivo junto com a pasta temporária.

Mas quero saber como obter apenas a pasta temporária.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php). Só isto :)

Comment: Bati meu recorde de resposta mais curta :D Logo eu :D

Comment: Puxa, o cara usou 30 caracteres (aplicando um trim) para dar a resposta!

Comment: Cai para 27 se removermos caracteres inúteis como ":)"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Tenta.

Comment: então cai p 16 se for deixar somente o necessário...